# Check if class has element from an array? and hide the ones not pressed

Tags: jquery, arrays, hide

Hi i'm trying to get something right.

First, I've got 12 menu items with an id. When the page is loaded i like to check if one or more of those id values are present in certain class.

Than i like to hide all the menu names (visually) witch are not pressed in the class.

The code so far: It doenst run the loop properly... or i dont make the array the right way

```
var test = $('.prov-nav').text().toLowerCase();
var cols = $.makeArray(test);
//alert(cols);

for ( var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++ )
{
if ( $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').hasClass( cols[i] ) )
{
 // .hide menu names (visually) witch are not pressed in the class
break;  
}
else
{
alert('o no');
}
```

The html menu: Of witch the non pressed name in the class('div[class^="cn-list-row"]') should be visually hidden. .hide from the menu. (not only the id but the menu link itself)

```
<ul class="prov-nav">
<li><a href="#">Drenthe</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Flevoland</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Friesland</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Gelderland</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Limburg</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Noord-Brabant</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Noord-Holland</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Overijssel</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Utrecht</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Zeeland</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Zuid-Holland</a></li><br/>
<ul><!-- end of prov-nav -->
```

The DIV class is (dynamically) loaded from a wp plugin caled connections. In the end i replace the hide with an animation to make them fade to low opacity. So you see clearly the option you selected earlier.

The class could contain different category's. The strange names are state names but then from Holland.

```
<div class="cn-list-row-alternate vcard cag_custom_st drenthe particulier sporttherapie"></div>
```

Comment: Dont get what you mean, can you describe what visual effect are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: The visual effect that hides the id's visually from the menu, the id's witch are not pressed in the class ('div[class^="cn-list-row"]'). So if only Drenthe is pressed in the class the rest of the menu except Drenthe should be hidden.

Comment: Can you show the DIV and explain the relationship better

Comment: Hope the edit of the original post gives you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using IDs is a very bad idea.

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav-li">Drenthe</li>
    <li class="nav-li">Flevoland</li>
    <li class="nav-li">Friesland</li>
    <li class="nav-li">Gelderland</li>
</ul>

$('.nav-li').click(function (){
   $(this).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

classes are a way of grouping similar objects together so you don't have to use the IDs for each item :)

Comment: Guess your right I was just about to delete them. But though they could be useful for giving them some specific values. Which is pointless now because the text is the same as the id.

Comment: Well if worse comes to worse you can use `:contains()` or `.eq()` or even more so, you can use multiple classes `nav-li drenthe` so if you ever need that u can use `$('.nav-li.drenthe')` same as using an id but u got it as a class as well as id[ish] :)